# android navigation drawer recreating fragments everytime

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am loading a simple navigation drawer with 3 fragments inside. When i go to 1st fragment and click a button in that fragment then the buttons background color is changed then i am navigating to second fragment and again i am coming back to the 1st fragment i want my fragment (With color changed button) in the backstack. But it is recreated everytime. I have tried multiple ways no luck. Since i am new to fragments i am stuck with this.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Fragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Fragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Fragment3.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    static Fragment fragment = null;

    private static final String FRAGMENT1_TAG = "FRAGMENT1_TAG";
    private static final String FRAGMENT2_TAG = "FRAGMENT2_TAG";
    private static final String FRAGMENT3_TAG = "FRAGMENT3_TAG";

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        navigateToFragment(id);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    public void navigateToFragment(int itemId) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        String FRAGMENT_TAG="";

        switch (itemId) {

            case R.id.nav_fragment1:

                FRAGMENT_TAG = FRAGMENT1_TAG;
                fragment = Fragment1.newInstance();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_fragment2:

                FRAGMENT_TAG = FRAGMENT2_TAG;
                fragment = Fragment2.newInstance();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_fragment3:

                FRAGMENT_TAG = FRAGMENT3_TAG;
                fragment = Fragment3.newInstance();
                break;

            default:

                FRAGMENT_TAG = FRAGMENT1_TAG;
                fragment = Fragment1.newInstance();
                break;

        }

        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment inputFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);

        if (inputFragment == null) {

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        } else {

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, inputFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the code of `Fragment2.newInstance();` to know better the behaviour.

This code probably solve your problem:

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Fragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        Fragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Fragment3.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    static Fragment fragment1 = null;
    static Fragment fragment2 = null;
    static Fragment fragment3 = null;

    private static final String FRAGMENT1_TAG = "FRAGMENT1_TAG";
    private static final String FRAGMENT2_TAG = "FRAGMENT2_TAG";
    private static final String FRAGMENT3_TAG = "FRAGMENT3_TAG";

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        navigateToFragment(id);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

    public void navigateToFragment(int itemId) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        String FRAGMENT_TAG="";

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (itemId) {

            case R.id.nav_fragment2:

                FRAGMENT_TAG = FRAGMENT2_TAG;
                if(fragment2 == null) fragment2 = Fragment2.newInstance();
                fragment = fragment2;
                break;

            case R.id.nav_fragment3:

                FRAGMENT_TAG = FRAGMENT3_TAG;
                if(fragment3 == null) fragment3 = Fragment3.newInstance();
                fragment = fragment3;
                break;

            default:

                FRAGMENT_TAG = FRAGMENT1_TAG;
                if(fragment1 == null) fragment1 = Fragment1.newInstance();
                fragment = fragment1;
                break;

        }

        FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment inputFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);

        if (inputFragment == null) {

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        } else {

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, inputFragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

I recommend you to refactor a little bit your code to get a more elegant solution.

Be sure that you're using `fragmentTransaction.add()` to add a fragment for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Use stack to keep track on fragment.
Check below link for reference.

https://github.com/rathodchintan/Fragment-Back-Stack

1.do not use replace method if you don't want to reload your fragment.
Instead you it use add method with keeping fragment object in the stack.

2. if you want to use replace, than check whether fragment is their in the memory by using findFragmentByTag method, and if it's not null use it else create new fragment.